# Break line in long label text

Tags: label, google-apps-script

Is there any trick to break a **label** text? Because '\n' '\r' '\n\r' don't work.
Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

if you use  those [2 parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_label#setWordWrap) you do what you want don't you ?

```
app.createLabel(text).setWidth(width).setWordWrap(true)
```

here is an example (among other widgets ;-):

```
function showurl() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.setTitle("Anchor in a popup ;-)");
  var panel = app.createFlowPanel()
  var image = app.createImage('https://sites.google.com/site/appsscriptexperiments/home/photo.jpg').setPixelSize(50, 50)
  var link = app.createAnchor('This is your link', 'https://sites.google.com/site/appsscriptexperiments/home');
  var lab = app.createLabel("wrap it because it's too narrow").setWidth(90).setWordWrap(true);
  var quit = app.createButton('quit');
  panel.add(image).add(link).add(lab).add(quit);
  app.add(panel);
   var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  doc.show(app);
}
```

EDIT : I found an [old post](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/apps-script/break%2420line%2420toast/apps-script/AaUea3SRPto/DnoRr6sR4xsJ)(on the Google group forum, thanks again Henrique ;-) about breaking lines in toast messages and here is the code I used for that case... the principle should work for Labels too but I didn't try.
To use it, just use \n (where you want to break the line) in a variable containing your text and pass it through this function. (there are some comment in the script to explain)

```
function break_(msg){
var temp = escape(msg);// shows codes of all chars
msg = unescape(temp.replace(/%20/g,"%A0")); // replace spaces by non break spaces
temp = msg.replace("\n"," "); // and replace the 'newline' by a normal space
  return temp; // send back the result
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Serge. I tried this one: createLabel(text, wordWrap) and doesn't work. I think HTML will be the solution until Label will not be sorted out...

Comment: Oops :) I'm with you. You're right. I wasn't precise.
Is there any trick to break a label text at the character where I want?

Comment: Yes, HTML does the work...
var HTML= app.createHTML( 'text1 <br>' +
                             'text1 <br>' +
                             'text1' );

Comment: ah !, too bad, I didn't see your last comment before posting... anyway, I'll leave it there... who knows ? could be helpfull for someone else ;-)

Comment: Thanks Serge, yes let's leave it there

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work?

```
//takes a line of text and returns a flex table broken by \n

function breakLabel(text) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var flexTable = app.createFlexTable();

  text = text.split('\n'); // split into an array 

  for (var i=0; i<text.length; i++){
    flexTable.setWidget(i, 0, app.createLabel(text[i].toString()));
  }

  return flexTable;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding them to a vertical panel helps as well (not the way you want, but still..):

```
var vPanel = app.createVerticalPanel().setSize(100,100);
var label = app.createLabel('predominantly blabla blala blabla');
app.add(vPanel.add(label));
```

See [reference](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.label.html)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone just now stumbling upon this, the best solution seems to be creating an HTML output for anything that needs line breaks.

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#showuserinterface)

```
 var htmlApp = HtmlService
     .createHtmlOutput('<p>A change of speed, a change of style...</p>')
     .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
     .setTitle('My HtmlService Application')
     .setWidth(250)
     .setHeight(300);

 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(htmlApp);

 // The script resumes execution immediately after showing the dialog.
```